# phonegap build app in android geolocation timesout

Tags: android, cordova, gps, geolocation

I've been trying to figure this out for over a month so its probably something really simple that I missed. I get the message "code: 3 message: Position retreival timed out."

**LOCATION CALL**

```
  var watchID = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(watchSuccess, watchError, { timeout: 30000, enableHighAccuracy: true });
```

**CONFIG.XML**

```
    <feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation"/>
            <gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.geolocation"  />

Under watchSuccess I have the following code:
console.log("accuracy: " + position.accuracy + "LAT: " + position.lattitude + " LONG: " + position.longitude)
```

Comment: We were having this issue as well. What we found worked was by setting a maxAge and also setting enableHighAccuracy to false.

Comment: Could you tell me what version of phonegap you were using?

Comment: 3.4.0. The only problem was that it worked for most devices, but not all, so it isn't a complete solution.